# Rete object not freeing Values after reset

Tags: java, jess

I am using Jess together with a FixThreadPool to create several Rete engines that can be used to evaluate the performance of a system in a parallel mode. Each Rete engine runs independently from the others and takes as an input a Java object containing the design of the system and outputs another Java object that contains its performance metrics.

Before evaluating each system, I reset the Rete engines to their original state. However, as my program runs the RAM memory keeps piling up, with more and more jess.Value objects being stored.

This is the class that I use to interface Jess with Java:

```
public class Variant {

    private final Object value;
    private final String type;

    public Variant(Object value) {
        this.value = cast2JavaObject(value);
        this.type = (this.value instanceof List) ? "multislot" : "slot";
    }

    public Object getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    private Object cast2JavaObject(Object value) {
        try {
            if (value instanceof Value) {
                return castJessValue((Value) value);
            } else {
                return value;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    private synchronized Object castJessValue(Value value) throws Exception {
        if (value.type() == RU.LIST) {
            List list = new ArrayList<Object>();
            list.addAll(Arrays.asList((Object[]) RU.valueToObject(Object.class, value, null)));
            return list;
        } else {
            return RU.valueToObject(Object.class, value, null);
        }
    }

    public Value toJessValue() throws Exception {
        Object val;
        if (value instanceof List) {
            val = ((List) value).toArray();
        } else {
            val = value;
        }
        return RU.objectToValue(val.getClass(), val);
    }
}
```

Is it possible that the Object contained within the Variant is pointing to the contents of a jess.Value and therefore they are not being collected by the GC when I call rete.reset()?

Answer (score 0):

I think that this would be possible if the object passed in the constructor (be it a jess.Value or a plain POJO) references one or more jess.Value's. Neither your cast2JavaObject nor RU.valueToObject are recursive + introspective.

However, what if there *were* jess.Value objects contained? They are decorations for Java objects, and even if they were unwrapped the heap would be piling up with the bared objects alone, just slower.

If you use store/fetch I'd also call clearStorage in addition to reset.

I suggest an experiment to narrow the OOM problem down. Rather than reset, recreate the Rete object. If the problem persists, I daresay it is in some other nook or cranny of your application.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have run the experiment and if I clear() the rete object rather than reset() it then the RAM is freed.

After some VM profiling I realized that both jess.Context and jess.Token are the two objects that keep increasing in size.